# Need to get the values from 2 calender funtions, find the difference and store it in label widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, calendar, nested-function

i have tried most things possible here but could get it to work. any help would be highly appreciated.

I want the users to select the dates AND THEN get theose values, storeit in  a and b, find the difference, and store it in y.

But what is actually happening is, when i call cal_fun1, it gets the value of b even before allowing the user selection.

how can i change this? Also i need the value to be stored in L3, as the difference.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry


    def pay_cal():

        def cal_fun():
            t = Toplevel()
            global cal
            cal = Calendar(t, year=2019, month=6, day=1, foreground='Blue', background='White', selectmode='day')
            cal.pack()
            cal.bind("<<CalendarSelected>>",lambda e: c.set(cal.get_date()))#make use of the virtual event to dynamically update the text variable c


        def cal_fun1():
            t = Toplevel()
            global cal1, y
            cal1 = Calendar(t, foreground='Blue', background='White', selectmode='day')
            cal1.pack()
            cal1.bind("<<CalendarSelected>>", lambda e: d.set(cal1.get_date()) ) # make use of the virtual event to dynamically update the text variable c
            a=cal.selection_get()
            b=cal1.selection_get()
            y =a-b
            print(y)    #this is only for testing the output

        sub_win = Tk()
        sub_win.geometry('400x500+600+100')
        sub_win.title('Payout Calculator')
        c = StringVar() #create a stringvar here - note that you can only create it after the creation of a TK instance
        c.set(0)
        d = StringVar()  # create a stringvar here - note that you can only create it after the creation of a TK instance
        d.set(0)
        y = StringVar()




        l1 = Button(sub_win, text= 'Check-In Date:', command= cal_fun)
        chck_in_date = Label(sub_win, textvariable=c)
        l1.grid(row=1)
        chck_in_date.grid(row=1, column=2)



        l2 = Button(sub_win, text='Can Date:', command=cal_fun1)
        q = Label(sub_win, textvariable=d)
        l2.grid(row=2)
        q.grid(row=2, column=2)



        total_days = Label(sub_win, textvariable= y.get())
        L3 = Label(sub_win, text="Total Days")
        L3.grid(row=3)
        total_days.grid(row=3, column=2)




        sub_win.mainloop()

    pay_cal()
```

Comment: Is there a reason for nested functions? What returns b=cal1.selection_get() or what do you expect?

Comment: pay_cal() has buttons that call on each of the nested functions. b returns the user selected date when cal_fun1() is called.